Matplotlib Chart bring xticks lables to the front
I found a wonderful example to plot a radar chart in python's matplotlib from this answer.
My xtick labels are quite long and reach into the radar chart. The label text is thus covered by the lines of the radar chart as shown in the screenshot below. Unfortunately, the label is even cut off from the chart area. I already tried the plt.tight_layout() to fix it, but didn't work.

Is there a way to either:

Preferred: Put the xtick labels at the outside of the chart, so they don't
overlapp with the chart at all

Put the label text in the front/change transparency with the alpha
parameter? e.g. plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), alpha=1) - didn't work


and to get all labels in the chart area so they are not cut off?
The code I use is:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def create_radar(df, *, id_column, title=None, max_values=None, padding=1.25, width=9, length=9):
    cm = 1/2.54
    categories = df._get_numeric_data().columns.tolist()
    data = df[categories].to_dict(orient='list')
    ids = df[id_column].tolist()
    if max_values is None:
        max_values = {key: padding*max(value) for key, value in data.items()}

    normalized_data = {key: np.array(value) / max_values[key] for key, value in data.items()}
    num_vars = len(data.keys())
    tiks = list(data.keys())
    tiks += tiks[:1]
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False).tolist() + [0]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width*cm, length*cm), subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))

    for i, model_name in enumerate(ids):
        values = [normalized_data[key][i] for key in data.keys()]
        actual_values = [data[key][i] for key in data.keys()]
        values += values[:1]  # Close the plot for a better look
        ax.plot(angles, values, label=model_name)
        ax.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.15)
        for _x, _y, t in zip(angles, values, actual_values):
            if isinstance(t, float) and t > 1:
                t = f'{t:.0f}'
            elif isinstance(t, float) and t <= 1:
                t = f'{t:.2%}'
            else:
                str(t)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                ax.text(_x, _y+.02, t, size='xx-small', va='top', ha='right')
            else:
                ax.text(_x, _y-.02, t, size='xx-small', va='bottom', ha='left')

    ax.fill(angles, np.ones(num_vars + 1), alpha=0.05)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_xticks(angles)
    #pos_list = np.arange(len(tiks))
    #ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator((pos_list)))
    #ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter((tiks)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(tiks, size="xx-small")
    ax.legend(loc='lower right',
              #bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 0.1)
              )

    if title is not None:
        plt.suptitle(title)
    plt.show()

radar = create_radar

create_radar(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'x': [*'abcde'],
        'supeeeer long category name 1': [10,11,12,13,14],
        'supeeeer long category name 2': [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9],
        'supeeeer long category name 4': [1e5, 2e5, 3.5e5, 8e4, 5e4],
        'supeeeer long category name 5': [9, 12, 5, 2, 0.2],
        'supeeeer long category name 6': [1,1,1,1,5]
    }),
    id_column='x',
)

produces:


can you provide some sample data so we can reproduce this?

@iBeMeltin - I added some data and a function call that reproduces the label issue.

You will get more help on this with a minimal self-contained example.  This example is far from minimal

ax.set_axisbelow(False) will make the tick labels appear in from of the plot. Perhaps adding some line breaks will help you fit the labels on the outside of the chart area
